# using d3 to visualize data in a webmapping application built with Openlayers

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, gis, openlayers-3

I am trying to build a web mapping application using openlayers 3 for map interaction and d3 to visualize data on the map , i tried this example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/d3.html but it seems it didn't work; there is a problem of precesion as you can see in this picture :[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeeOs.png)
here is my code:

```
var canvasNbr = function(extent, resolution, pixelRatio,
  size, projection) {
var canvasWidth = size[0];
var canvasHeight = size[1];

var canvas = d3.select(document.createElement('canvas'));
canvas.attr('width', canvasWidth).attr('height', canvasHeight);

var context = canvas.node().getContext('2d');

var d3Projection = d3.geo.conicConformal() 
. scale ( 1 );
var d3Path = d3.geo.path().projection(d3Projection);


var pixelBounds = d3Path.bounds(regions);
var pixelBoundsWidth = pixelBounds[1][0] - pixelBounds[0][0];
var pixelBoundsHeight = pixelBounds[1][1] - pixelBounds[0][1];

var geoBounds = d3.geo.bounds(regions);
var geoBoundsLeftBottom = ol.proj.transform(
    geoBounds[0], 'EPSG:4326', projection);
var geoBoundsRightTop = ol.proj.transform(
    geoBounds[1], 'EPSG:4326', projection);
var geoBoundsWidth = geoBoundsRightTop[0] - geoBoundsLeftBottom[0];
if (geoBoundsWidth < 0) {
  geoBoundsWidth += ol.extent.getWidth(projection.getExtent());
}
var geoBoundsHeight = geoBoundsRightTop[1] - geoBoundsLeftBottom[1];

var widthResolution = geoBoundsWidth / pixelBoundsWidth;
var heightResolution = geoBoundsHeight / pixelBoundsHeight;
var r = Math.max(widthResolution, heightResolution);
var scale = r / (resolution / pixelRatio);

var center = ol.proj.transform(ol.extent.getCenter(extent),
    projection, 'EPSG:4326');
d3Projection.scale(scale).center(center)
    .translate([canvasWidth / 2, canvasHeight / 2]);
d3Path = d3Path.projection(d3Projection).context(context);

d3Path(regions);
context.stroke();


return canvas[0][0];
};
var nbrLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
  source: new ol.source.ImageCanvas({
    canvasFunction: canvasNbr,
    projection: 'EPSG:4326'
  })
});
map.addLayer(nbrLayer);
```

also i want to know how to do this  [d3 map example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgveA.png) in openlayers
here is the code using d3:

```
// radius of circles
var radius = d3
  .scaleSqrt()
  .domain([0, 164])
  .range([0, 15]);
// define colors
  var colorScale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateBlues).domain([0,165]);
// scale legend
const scaleLegend=[10,50,100,150,200]
svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(regions.features)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("fill",(d:any)=> colorScale(d.properties.nbr_cas))
  .attr("cx", function (d:any) {return projection([d.properties.long,d.properties.lat])[0]; })
  .attr("cy", function (d:any) { return projection([d.properties.long,d.properties.lat])[1]; })
  .attr("r",(d:any)=> radius(d.properties.nbr_cas));
```

Comment: The example you link to works, without seeing how you've adopted the example to your needs it's difficult to fix your issue, if you share the relevant code, any error messages you get, and what your result looks like, you're much more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: i really thank you Mr. Andrew for your reply. i'll explain my problem in a answer as you suggested thank you very much

Comment: I'll just add that you should add the detail into your question - you can edit it, answers with clarifications on the question usually aren't well received as that's not what they are intended for.

Comment: thank you very much  Mr.Andrew i add clarifications in my question

Comment: Great, while someone might answer in the meantime, I'll have some time to take a closer look in the next day or two - things are a bit hectic at the moment. Though, at a glance it appears you are mixing a conic projection with a web mercator (used for the tiles), if you try using `d3.geo.mercator` you might have better results.

Comment: i tried with mercator also but i still have the same problem, is there another way without using d3 or a cartographic server just using openlayers ? and thank you Mr.Andrew